# Temporarily preventing helm from reading the mini-buffer

Tags: helm, minibuffer

I use `helm` to select research papers for citation. I am currently trying to implement a command that would sort papers based on multiple criteria selected by the user. The input for this command (i.e. the sorting criteria) is obtained by using  `completing-read-multiple`. To enable `completing-read-multiple` to use the mini-buffer (which had been used by `helm` for inputting the filter), I set `enable-recursive-minibuffers` to `t`. The problem is that `helm` interprets the input to `completing-read-multiple` as part of the filter. How do I avoid this? That is, how do I temporarily prevent `helm` from reading the mini-buffer.

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your command?